# Lines of Code that came in the New Project - Android

Tags: android

So I created a new project and the following came up as part of the default start code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.phone_start_screen, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Coincidently I am trying to learn Android coding and there are parts similar to what I'm currently reading, fragments. However I do no understand the code above, I do not even know when it is being called and well I do not understand fragments but thats another matter and I will continue trying to learn that. At the moment I would just like an explanation on the code above.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: Refer to the [Android documentation on menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu` usually gets called when the user presses the Menu button. In the case of an action bar presence though, the method will actually get called before `onCreate` finishes.

As to what code does, it [inflates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html) the `phone_start_screen.xml` (in your example) from the /res/menu folder.